# Images won't show in slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

The first image will appear but then the rest won't. I don't think the script can locate them. How do I direct it to my images?

JavaScript:

```
var myImgage=document.getElementById("slideshow");

var imageArray=["healing.jpg","holiday.jpg","nye.jpg","basketball.jpg"]

var imageIndex=0;

function changeImage () {
    slideshow.setAttribute("src", imageArray [imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++; 
    if (imageIndex>=imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex=0;
    }
}

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,2000);
    slideshow.onclick=function () {
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);
}
```

HTML:

```html
<img id="slideshow" src="image/healing.jpg" width="80%" height="40%"/>
<script src="java/slideshow.js"></script>
```

Comment: In the first line you define "myImgage" but later you use some variable called "slideshow". Did you miss something pasting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your imageArray to the following

```
var imageArray=["image/healing.jpg","image/holiday.jpg","image/nye.jpg","image/basketball.jpg"]
```

Comment: that would take up a lot of bytes, instead change the `slideshow.setAttribute("src", imageArray [imageIndex]);` to this: `slideshow.setAttribute("src", "image/" + imageArray[imageIndex]);`

Comment: No problem at all! You'll often find when loading images and scripts you need to make sure you are loading the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `slideshow` variable with `myImgage`. Also fix your images path by adding `image/` in the images array.